# Migration of Rule Engine drools 6.5.0.Final to 7.73.0.Final

Tags: drools

We are upgrading java version of our service from 11 to 17, due to which drools upgrade is required  for java 17 compatibility. but facing issues in loading drl files if the feature name and corresponding threshold value that is used in drl contains common numericals. Lets say if feature name is abcd_123 and drl is not getting loaded if the rule is abcd_123 <= 1 or abcd_123 <= 2 or abcd_123 <=3 but no issues were there if the rule is abcd_123 <= 4.

is there a solution for this rather than changing the drl file

The loading of ruleset is failing at KieContainer creation stage.

```
private KieContainer createKieContainer(String identifier, byte[] drlBlob) throws RulesSDKException {
    if (this.containerHashMap.containsKey(identifier)) {
        return (KieContainer)this.containerHashMap.get(identifier);
    } else {
        Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drlBlob);
        KieServices kieServices = org.kie.api.KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write("src/main/resources/" + identifier + ".drl", resource);
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
        Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
        if (results.hasMessages(new Message.Level[]{Level.ERROR})) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to load RuleSet " + results.getMessages());
            throw new RulesSDKException("Unable to load RuleSet " + results.getMessages());
        } else {
            KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
            this.containerHashMap.put(identifier, kieContainer);
            return kieContainer;
        }
    }
}
```

this is failing at "Results results = kieBuilder.getResults()" and the logs show the below

```
Unable to Analyse Expression rule_ekart_90.0 >= 90.0:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: double.0()]
[Near : {... rule_ekart_90.0 >= 90.0 ....}]
                                                             ^ : [Rule name='RULE_2.1']
```

DRL file :

```
package rule_table;
//generated from Decision Table
function boolean isStringEmpty(String s) { 
         if(s.isEmpty()) {  
             return true; 
        } 
             return false; 
  }
// rule values at A63, header at A6
rule "RULE_2.1"
    when
        fact:Fact(rule_ekart_90 >=90)
    then
        fact.getReasonCodes().add(new ReasonCode("DECISION",drools.getRule().getName(), “reason_decision”));
        fact.getActions().add(new Action("DECISION",drools.getRule().getName(), “action_decision”));
end
```

Comment: Please share an actual code example of the DRL that "loads" in Drools 6.5.0 but not 7.73.0 (plus the example for the DRL that works in both). Also the code which you're using to "load" said rules and how you're verifying that a particular rule is "loaded" or not.

Comment: What exactly is `rule_ekart_90` in the Fact model ? I notice that in the DRL you posted, you have `Fact(rule_ekart_90 >= 90)` and in the error message you have a reference to `rule_ekart_90.0 >= 90.0` which is not present in the DRL.

Comment: rule_ekart_90 is a variable in our service which we send it to rules engine, and when this drl is parsed the variable name is read as rule_ekart_90.0 instead of rule_ekart_90

Comment: The comments indicate that this originated as a decision table; can you take a screenshot of the columns that generate this specific rule? You can hide the unrelated columns/rules.